# STM32F412/413 USB changes from STM32F411

Tags: usb, stm32

I have a project that was previously using STM32F411, and I am trying to swap over to using a STM32F412 (UQFN48, so pin compatible).

I thought I should be able to use the STM32F411 firmware on the STM32F412 (just not using the extra RAM/flash). I can flash it over USB DFU (so the hardware works) and the firmware itself runs fine (so clock speeds are fine), but USB does not work on it.

Does anyone know what changed on USB between chip versions that would stop the F411's code from working on F412? Is it just a matter of flipping some bits in a register?

Thanks!

Comment: Quick compare of USB register map of both MCUs shows some differences in registers so it would depend on actual code, but it could be a problem.

Comment: Thanks - I'd compared the MCU-specific header files and found no real differences, but it looks like the USB peripheral has its own headers. There do appear to be the same registers at the same addresses, but there are definitely some extra bitfields in there

Comment: I should add that USB doesn't even seem to be getting picked up. Running 'dmesg' on the PC it's connecting to leaves no notification that its even connected

Comment: I thought first of vddusb but it is not available for UQFN48 I think.

Comment: F411 and F412 have different version of the USB core. F411 has version 1.2 while F412 has version 2.0. See the respective USB core ID registers. What USB library are you using. STM32 HAL?

Comment: Thanks! That's good to know. I believe it's the HAL - it's `usbd_core 2.4.0` and `stm32f4xx_ll_usb`/`stm32f4xx_hal_*`. ST's current USB libraries have a lower version number and seem completely incompatible but I'm getting slightly further trying to build with a version `2.4.2` I found online which at least mentions the F412 in the code

Comment: Updating from 2.4.0 to 2.4.2 fixed it! I'll still need to try and figure out *why* though, since the new libraries have now stopped the F411 build from working

Answer (score 3):

The clock configuration for the F412 is significantly more complicated than that for the F411. If you refer to the [F12 Reference Manual](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/dm00180369-stm32f412-advanced-armbased-32bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf), page 112, you find Figure 13:
[image]

Compare that to the [F411 Reference Manual](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/dm00119316-stm32f411xce-advanced-armbased-32bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf), page 93, Figure 12:
[image]

So there are at least 2 extra bits which need to be correctly configured just to get the 48MHz clock enabled for the USB module.

In addition to this there are some new bits in the F412 USB registers, but (at least superficially) it appears that these shouldn't have any effect as long as they're left at their default/reset values.

Comment: Thanks! That's really helpful! I just checked and the CK48MSEL bit in RCC_DCKCFGR2 does at least seem to have the correct reset value (0 = PLL) but even so it does seem like there are some pretty serious differences between devices